# How do I return an array, when I only want the values above 5 in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have the array

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 7, 9, 8, 12, 1, 8};
```

I want to write a method that returns only values above 5. And I can't figure it out.

The only thing I manage to do, is returning every single value, I can't seem to assign the return integer to only use values above 5.

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: You can create a method that returns an `int[]`, inside it you create a new int array and fill it with the values you need.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - [The Homework Tag Is Now Officially Depricated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?newsletter=1&nlcode=95043|8eb5)

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen I didn't know about it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

*Here are the steps you need to follow: -*

- `Iterate` over the array and access each element
- For each element, check whether it's value is `greater than 5` or not.
- If it is greater than 5, you can add it to a `temporary array`
- At the end of the iteration, you can `return` the `temporary array`

But, if you use array, you are bound to create your temporary array of the same size as of the original array.. That can be a waste of memory, particularly when, you don't find any element greater than 5..

A better option would be to go for [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which you can create on the fly, and can add elements dynamically.. Thus you won't have to bother about size.. Check out the `documentation link` for more information..

Comment: If the need of a `int[]` type is *really* necessary over a `Collection` (aka `ArrayList`) then it may be possible to perform two iterations; first to determine how many values are greater than 5, *then* creating the `int` array and setting the values into it. I believe that it is comparable to using an `ArrayList` since the internal array of `Object` managed by the implementation perform some resizing, and with a large source array, the amount of resizing would justify not using it, in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

You should return an array as well.

```
ArrayList<Integer> getGreaterThanFive(int[] numbers)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int number : numbers)
    {
        if (number > 5)
        {
            result.add(number);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 7, 9, 8, 12, 1, 8};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<=numbers.length-1; i++ ){
        if(numbers[i]>5){
            list.add(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List :"+list);
```

Comment: Use foreach loop wherever you can, its more readable and harder to make a mistake.